# How to access a nested Python dictionary key-value pair when the key location in the hierarchy is not known in advance?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested Python dictionary and need to set a certain key to a certain value. For example,

```
x['key1']['key2']['key3'] = value
```

This works if I know the hierarchy in advance. This is not the case. I am looking for an addressing scheme like 'key1/key2/key3' that could be specified at run time to access the desired key-value pair. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As just the very beginning of an approach, you can parse a string like `'key1/key2/key3'` into a function that would do what you want. For example:

```
# Assuming for this example that s is just a `/`-delimted string of keys.
def make_getter(s):
    keys = s.split("/")
    def _(d):
        rv = d
        for k in keys:
            try:
                rv = rv.get(k)
            except AttributeError:
                rv = None
                break
        return rv
    return d
```

Then

```
>>> accessor = make_getter("foo/bar/baz")
>>> accessor({'foo': {'bar': {'baz': 3}}})
3
>>> accessor({'foo': 9})
None
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a recursive approach to search through the nested dictionary representation until you find 'key1' then return the [key1][key2][key3] lookup. This assumes that key1 is not duplicated in the data-structure.

```
In [9]: def lookup(key, nested_dict):
   ...:     for k, v in nested_dict.items():
   ...:         if k == key:
   ...:             return v
   ...:         if isinstance(v, dict):
   ...:             val = lookup(key, v)
   ...:             if val:
   ...:                 return val
   ...:     return None

In [10]: a = {'b' :{'c':{'d':1}}, 'f':2}
In [11]: lookup('d', a)
Out[11]: 1

In [12]: lookup('b', a)
Out[12]: {'c': {'d': 1}}

In [13]: lookup('c', a)
Out[13]: {'d': 1}
```